# Gradle dependency for specific architecture with ABI splits

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

Im facing this problem which seems im not able to solve. Here is scenario:

Im building apk which uses gradle dependency and **this dependency is architecture specific** so for apk for x86 i need different dependency and for arm different as well.

I solved it with product flavors:

```
productFlavors {

   dev { ... }
   develx86 { ... }
   production { ... }
   productionx86 { ... }

}
```

So then i defined dependency like this:

```
develCompile 'dependency_for_arm'
develx86Compile 'dependency_for_x86'
```

This works good. But recently i had to add to my application an usage of renderscript. I did it in this way:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 22
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

And after this when i uploaded apk on Google Play it says it's apk is suitable with arm, x86. I don't know how this is possible. As you can think it will crash on device with different CPU (if i generated apk for arm and user will execute it on x86 app will crash).

So i decited to use ABI splits:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi', 'x86'
            universalApk false
        }
    }

//Ensures architecture specific APKs have a higher version code
//(otherwise an x86 build would end up using the arm build, which x86 devices can run)
ext.versionCodes = [armeabi:0, x86:1]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        int abiVersionCode = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) ?: 0
        output.versionCodeOverride = android.defaultConfig.versionCode + abiVersionCode
    }
```

But now when i see generated apk files, my dependency which is **flavor-specific** is not included into apk and apk will crash when i open section which uses API from this dependency.

Do someone know how to solve this issue? Or someone know why Google Play says that apk is for both architectures when i included renderscript? (Without it it works properly but i need renderscript).

Thank you for your time. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: any luck ? Please post the answer if you have found it

Answer (score 2):

If you look inside your APK, under *lib* folder, you should see that renderscript support mode added libs for other architectures than the one you're supporting.

You can keep your earlier configuration with ABI-specific flavors.
But in order to ensure that no libs for other architectures are included, try adding abiFilters to your flavors:

```
productFlavors {

   dev { ... ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' }
   develx86 { ... ndk.abiFilters 'x86' }
   production { ... ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' }
   productionx86 { ... ndk.abiFilters 'x86' }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment inline yet.

What's in the apk, especially in res/raw/ and lib/?
Also, are you using gradle-plugin 2.1.0? (since you are using `renderscriptTargetApi 22`), have you tried Build-Tools 23.0.3?